# How to Write a not equal to in unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement

How to write a not equal to on an if statement in unity c#. I want to write

```
 if (other.CompareTag not equal to ("Score_Trigger")){ }
```

I tried

```
if(!other.CompareTag("Score_Trigger"))
       {}
```

Comment: And did it work?

Comment: Do you ever print`other.tag` ? And sure it not equal.

Comment: @MatthiasTylkowski no it didn't

Comment: [`CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html) returns a `bool` so you negate it using `!` as any other `bool` value ... if it is `not working` something else is wrong in your script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your attempt and it went through without any problems. Check, if everything outside of this if statement is set up properly.
Be aware, that the Object you are trying to compare needs a tag.

```
if (!a.CompareTag("test"))
{
    Debug.Log("is not equal...");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the unity docs https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html

The usage is described with

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Given you only did other.CompareTag, perhaps this is the reason your code failed.  other would be the collider/trigger which of course doesnt have a tag

Therefore the test should be `if (!other.gameObject.CompareTag("Score_Trigger")...`

Comment: I guess the example is only a bit messed up / lazy ... since `Component.CompareTag` is part of `Component` it should be possible to use it on the `Collider` directly without using `gameObject` which would be [`GameObject.CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.CompareTag.html) ^^ Doesn't count of course for [`OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html) where you get a `Collision` instead In this case you **have to** use either `gameObject`, `collider`, `transform` or `rigidbody`

Answer (score 1):

Well if what you tried didn't work, then you can try one of the following solutions:

```
 if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Score_Trigger"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Equal");
        }
        else
        {
         Debug.Log("Not Equal");
        }
```

```
if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Score_Trigger") == false)
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: depending on what `other` is this does exactly the same only written different. since `Component.CompareTag` is part of `Component` it should be possible to use it on the `Collider` directly without using `gameObject` which would be [`GameObject.CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.CompareTag.html) ^^ Doesn't count of course for [`OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html) where you get a `Collision` instead In this case you **have to** use either `gameObject`, `collider`, `transform` or `rigidbody`

Answer (score 0):

your second attempt should be working fine, but you could also do

```
if (other.tag != "Score_Trigger")
```

or

```
if (other.gameObject.tag != "Score_Trigger")
```